# MS Access - Customized Price List

Tags: ms-access

In MS Access, I've got Table A that lists products with the price for each product and Table B with Customer Name, Customer ID and the Profit Margin associated for each customer.

What I need to do is create a customized price list for each customer based on their profit margin. Each customer will receive the exact same list of products from Table A. The only difference being that the price column in Table A will change depending on the Profit Margin column contained in Table B.

Ultimately, I would use this to create a report that would then be emailed out to each customer.

I’m having some difficulty figuring out how to set it up so that all customers in Table A are linked to one price list with differing prices depending on their profit margin.

If anyone could help give me a push in the right direction I would greatly appreciate it.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you have the following tables:

1. **tblProducts**, with fields **Product** and **Cost**.
2. **tblCustomers**, with fields **Customer** and **Margin**.

I'm not sure how your margin works (is it a factor which is multiplied by the cost, or a fixed amount which is added on?), but the formula should be easy to work out to suit your needs.

Create a query. In query design mode, show the two tables. Add the field `tblProducts.Product` to your query, and the expression `[tblProducts].[Cost] * [tblCustomers].[Margin]`.

In the Criteria for this expression, you can set, for example, `[tblCustomers].[Customer] = "John"`. Or, instead of specifying a particular customer, you could reference a control on a form. In this way, changing the control on the form (eg. selecting a customer from a listbox) will change which customer's data the query is based on.

Then you can build a query on the report as usual.

Comment: Thanks very much for pointing me in the right direction. Really grateful for your help.

Comment: @Evans No worries, let me know if you need any further help. If the answer has helped, you could accept it (green tick)?